# APKs generated through Eclipse are accepted or not?

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I am a little new to Android development.

I have a hybrid app which uses Apache cordova plugins.

I am using eclipse to generate the APK.

But when I publish the APK, the Google play store rejects it saying:

**APP UPDATE REJECTED**

**Your APK has been rejected for containing security vulnerabilities, which violates the Malicious Behavior policy. The *Alerts page* has more information about how to resolve the issue. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still live on Google Play.**

And, when I click on the alerts page the following error shows up:

**Security alert :**

**Your app is using a version of Apache Cordova containing one or more security vulnerabilities. Please see this Google Help Center article for details, including the deadline for fixing the app.**

I have already tried the followings:

1. Update the android platform (cordova platform update android), but no positive results.
2. I could not update all the cordova plugins as I am getting errors. (wanted to know can this be the issue)
3. I am building this APK using the Eclipse IDE and I went through this ADT plugin release note https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html which says: **The Eclipse ADT plugin is no longer supported**

Eventually I will be importing my project to Android studio but I want an app update immediately thats why still using Eclipse.

If Eclipse is the reason then I immediately need to import my app to Android studio.

I want to figure out that which one of the last two point is responsible for my app rejection.

Also, if none of these are responsible then what could be the possible reason for my app rejection.

***Thanks in advance.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An APK is an APK, regardless of where you developed the code. You can write the code in Eclipse, Android Studio, or you can write the code in your favorite plain text editor. The end APK will be indistinguishable regardless of which editor you use.

The error in this case seems to be pretty clear- your version of Cordova has known vulnerabilities and you need to update that.

Run `cordova platform version android` to check your version. The error message you are receiving will show for anything less than 4.1.1.

The best path would probably be to upgrade to 5.x, [as detailed here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/upgrade.html).

Comment: will platform 6.x work? I have tried upgrading to 6.x.